# Assign an element value based on element adjacencies in R

Tags: r, element, assign

I have a data frame with {0,1} indicating whether a product was Small, Medium or Large.

```
dat <- data.frame(Sm = c(1,0,0), Med = c(0,1,0), Lg = c(0,0,1))

  Sm Med Lg
1  1   0  0
2  0   1  0
3  0   0  1
```

I'm looking to assign 1's to the 0's leading up to a 1 in a given row.  For example in row 2 the product is a "Med", so I'm looking to assign a 1 to the 0 in the "Sm" column.

Allocation size is a consideration so I'm looking for a vectorized approach without using a for loop please.  The final solution should output the following:

```
  Sm Med Lg
1  1   0  0
2  1   1  0
3  1   1  1
```

I've tried several variations of the code below, but the closest I can get is a ragged array which assigns all of the 1's correctly while dropping the elements that have legitimate 0's.

```
apply(dat, 1, function(x) {
    x[1:which.max(x)] <- 1
})

[1] 1 1 1
```

And below, which gets close but without the needed trailing 0's

```
apply(dat, 1, function(x) {
    temp <- x[1:which.max(x)]
    unlist(lapply(temp, function(y) {
        y <- 1
    }))
})

[[1]]
Sm 
1 
[[2]]
Sm Med 
1   1 
[[3]]
Sm Med  Lg 
1   1   1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, convert to matrix and use `max.col` to get the index of the `1` in each row:

```
mat <- as.matrix(dat)
mc  <- max.col(mat)
```

**logical construction** Overwrite the matrix:

```
mat = +(col(mat) <= mc)
```

or construct an index of matrix positions to change and change 'em:

**logical indexing**

```
mat[col(mat) < mc] <- 1L
# or
mat[which(col(mat) < mc)] <- 1L
```

**matrix indexing**

```
idx <- do.call( rbind, lapply( seq_along(mc), function(i) 
    if (i==1L) NULL 
    else       cbind(i,seq_len(mc[i]-1))
))

mat[idx] <- 1L
```

**vector indexing**

```
nr  <- nrow(mat)
idx <- unlist( lapply( seq_along(mc), function(i) 
  if (mc[i]==1L) NULL 
  else           seq(from = i, by = nr, length.out = mc[i]-1L) 
))

mat[idx] <- 1L
```

The help for all three indexing methods can be found at `help("[<-")`.

Comment: Thank you for the solutions.  Both work much better than the path I was headed down.  I think I'll go with the logical indexing as that does the trick with much less code.

Comment: All three of these methods are new to me so thank you for bringing them to my attention.  I will take a look at the help files and read up.  @Frank

Comment: @Brian By the way, I added a fourth at the top "logical construction" (not sure what to call it). It just uses normal symbols, so there's not much to look up. `+` with one argument converts a logical to 0/1.

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you want.

```
dat[which(dat$Med==1),]$Sm = 1
dat[which(dat$Lg==1),]$Med = 1
dat[which(dat$Lg==1),]$Sm = 1
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment, however the attribute names are never constant and I'll need to apply the code many times to different column groupings, so assigning manually is not an option.